# How to overwrite textDidChange: method correctly?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextfield

I subclassed NSTextField and overwrite the **textDidChange:** as:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // ... My own operation
}
```

But when I drag a input text box into my `.xib` file and control drag another class to assign the delegate I found the delegate's **`controlTextDidChange:`** method was never called.

Now tryingto solve this problem, I tried two ways al below:

I. calling `super`:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // ... My own operation
    [super textDidChange:notification];
}
```

But I got an error in runtime: *attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]*

II. calling `delegate`'s method

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // ... My own operation
    if ([self.delegate responseToSelector:@selector(controlTextDidChange:)])
    {
        [self.delegate ...];    // <--- Opps, something not happerned here.
    }
}
```

What not happerned? I expected that the auto-complete should display the `controlTextDidChange:` method at the position of `...` above. But it did not, actually. I typed the method directly, compilation fail because method not found.

How should I make my sub-class call the delegate normally? How should I overwrite the `textDidChange:` method correctly?

---

Further question for Vytautas:

1. I am sure I was using `NSTextField`. And I set a break point inside controlTextDidChange: method. As it was called, I should have known.
2. I did control-drag the text field to the delegate object, and I print delegate object in the `textDidChange:` method, it was sure that the delegate was set correctly.
3. The other delegate methods, such as `controlTextDidBeginEditing:` were called correctly. But `controlTextDidChange:` not called
4. I tried comment out the over-written in the subclassed `NSTextField` class, then `controlTextDidChange:` was called.
5. Therefore I was quite sure that I am not overwritting the `textDidChange:` right. But I do not known how to fix it.
6. What made me confused mostly was that why auto-completion did not show the `controlTextDidChange:` method when I attempted to call it.

About the auto-completion, here is how it showed:

[image]

No `- controlTextDidChange:` method.

---

2nd further reply for Vytautas:

I tried calling '[self controlTextDidChange]' but it did not work, and error occurred (as highlighted below):
[image]

Comment: Did you check that the delegate declared any necessary delegate protocol ?

Comment: Yes. I am quite sure that does no matter with the delegate. The auto completion fill the `controlTextDidChange` for me in the `responseToSelector:` method but I could not directly call it like format of `[self.delegate controlTextDidChange:notification];`.

Answer (score 1):

I can say that **`- controlTextDidChange:`** is called for sure.

Maybe there is something wrong with you bindings in your *.xib.

Also it can be that in *.xib you are using NSTextView, not NSTextField.

In this case **`- controlTextDidChange:`** won't be called for sure. 
If that is the case then you should take a look to `NSTextView`, `NSTextViewDelegate` and `NSTextDelegate`. NSTextView delegate has an alternative method for this **`- textDidChange:`**

Comment: I add some futrher description in my question text.

Comment: So, you are overwritting `-textDidChange:` of NSTextField, then take a look here: [`[NSControl controlTextDidChange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/controlTextDidChange:), there is some magic behind. As I remember, just call `[self controlTextDidChange:]` in your `[NSTextField textDidChange:]` implementation, and as parameter use same notification, which you have received.

Comment: It did not work as I posted in the question text. However, I found the solution: I could call `[self.delegate performSelector:@selector(controlTextDidChange:) withObject:notification];` and the delegate receive that successfully.

Comment: I will try to implement it by my self and I will let you know my solution

Comment: OK! It seemed that the `performSelector` is not a standard way.